# truncated incorrect INTEGER VALUE : 'EN_US'

Tags: mysql

got this error when  I tried to create a table 'top20bypopulation' from a select statement

query :

```
CREATE table top20bypopulation as
SELECT Name,format(Population,'EN_US') as population FROM country
ORDER BY Population DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

error :
**truncated incorrect INTEGER VALUE : 'EN_US'**

But the `SELECT` runs okey, but when I create table out of it, it gives this error.
I am new to this language, someone please answer how to achieve this.

Comment: [FORMAT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) - `locale` is 3rd parameter, not 2nd one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your country table Population column is integer and you are trying to get format value

so when we pass two parameter then first one is value and second parameter must be precisioin

if you want to pass locale as parameter then format method be like

```
format(Population,2,'EN_US')
```

Comment: `FORMAT(Population,0,'EN_US') `